# Fastest way to make a UIView hidden (setHidden:YES vs setAlpha:0)

Tags: iphone, performance, uiview

My goal is very simple: make a view hidden or visible. Two ways I am considering doing this is by either toggling UIView's setHidden or toggling the UIView's alpha from 0 to 1. 
Here's an example:

```
// set myView hidden
[myView setHidden:YES];
// vs
[myView setAlpha:0];

// set myView visible
[myView setHidden:NO];
// vs 
[myView setAlpha:1];
```

This may sound a bit pedantic but my question is regarding performance of UIView's setHidden: vs UIView's setAlpha: where the alpha will only be 0 or 1 where 0 hides the view and 1 makes it visible. Given the alpha will only be 0 or 1, is changing the alpha of a view computationally more expensive then hiding or showing a view?

Answer (score 1):

Try it out with some measuring:

```
NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];

// your code

NSDate *finishDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval executionTime = [finishDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
NSLog(@"Execution took %f seconds", executionTime);
```

But honestly, I don't think there will be a difference that's worth caring about.